# Can I use dd to verify unpartitioned disk surface?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, hard-drive, dd

The thing is, I bought a laptop and after 6 days of HDD uptime, the SMART reports "449 reallocated sectors" already. With number slowly, but constantly climbing.

My HD is 320GB in size, with only 100GB allocated, which are used by Ubuntu installation.

I would like to check the rest of the 220GB for bad sectors, so that I could RMA the disk if there are even more reallocations, but I don't know how to do it, being a Linux newbie.

The un-partitioned space seems to be `/dev/sda3`, so I was thinking about `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda3`, but I'm not sure if that won't wipe some critical partition table data or something.

Can anyone recommend me what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive is defective; RMA it.  With 449 reallocated, you don't need to bother with any more checks, but if you really want to, it is best to run the long smart selftest using the disk utility.

Also sda3 is the third partition, so it is not unpartitioned space.